# Pretraining neural net example in Aurelien Geron's book

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am testing the pretraining example in Chapter 15 of Aurélien Géron's book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow". The code is on his github page: [here](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/15_autoencoders.ipynb) - see the example in section "Unsupervised pretraining".

Pretraining the network with the weights from the previously trained encoder should assist in training the network. To check this I slightly modified Aurelien's code so it outputs the error after every batch, and also reduced the batch size. I did this so I could see the error at the start of the training, where the effect of the pretrained weights should have been most obvious. I expected the pretrained network would start with a lower error (compared to the network not using pretraining) because it was starting with pretrained weights. However the pretraining seems to make training slower.

Has anyone any idea why this could be?

The first few lines of output (when using pretraining) is:

```
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.08
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.24
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.32
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.2
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.32
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.26
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.32
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.5
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.58
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.48
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.54
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.48
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.5
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.56
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.64
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.56
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.68
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.62
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.74
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.78
```

As you can see the accuracy is initially low. In contrast, when using He-initialized weights (i.e. not using pretraining), the initial accuracy is actually higher:

```
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.62
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.5
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.52
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.38
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.56
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.56
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.6
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.7
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.72
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.86
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.86
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.8
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.82
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.84
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.88
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.9
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.82
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.9
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.84
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.98
0 Train accuracy after each mini-batch: 0.96
```

In other words, the pretraining seems to slow down training, the opposite of what it should be doing!

My modified code is:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


def reset_graph(seed=42):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)


def train_stacked_autoencoder():
    reset_graph()

    # Load the dataset to use
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/")

    n_inputs = 28 * 28
    n_hidden1 = 300
    n_hidden2 = 150  # codings
    n_hidden3 = n_hidden1
    n_outputs = n_inputs

    learning_rate = 0.01
    l2_reg = 0.0001

    activation = tf.nn.elu
    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(l2_reg)
    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])

    weights1_init = initializer([n_inputs, n_hidden1])
    weights2_init = initializer([n_hidden1, n_hidden2])
    weights3_init = initializer([n_hidden2, n_hidden3])
    weights4_init = initializer([n_hidden3, n_outputs])

    weights1 = tf.Variable(weights1_init, dtype=tf.float32, name="weights1")
    weights2 = tf.Variable(weights2_init, dtype=tf.float32, name="weights2")
    weights3 = tf.Variable(weights3_init, dtype=tf.float32, name="weights3")
    weights4 = tf.Variable(weights4_init, dtype=tf.float32, name="weights4")

    biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_hidden1), name="biases1")
    biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_hidden2), name="biases2")
    biases3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_hidden3), name="biases3")
    biases4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_outputs), name="biases4")

    hidden1 = activation(tf.matmul(X, weights1) + biases1)
    hidden2 = activation(tf.matmul(hidden1, weights2) + biases2)
    hidden3 = activation(tf.matmul(hidden2, weights3) + biases3)
    outputs = tf.matmul(hidden3, weights4) + biases4

    reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - X))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

    with tf.name_scope("phase1"):
        phase1_outputs = tf.matmul(hidden1, weights4) + biases4  # bypass hidden2 and hidden3
        phase1_reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(phase1_outputs - X))
        phase1_reg_loss = regularizer(weights1) + regularizer(weights4)
        phase1_loss = phase1_reconstruction_loss + phase1_reg_loss
        phase1_training_op = optimizer.minimize(phase1_loss)

    with tf.name_scope("phase2"):
        phase2_reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hidden3 - hidden1))
        phase2_reg_loss = regularizer(weights2) + regularizer(weights3)
        phase2_loss = phase2_reconstruction_loss + phase2_reg_loss
        train_vars = [weights2, biases2, weights3, biases3]
        phase2_training_op = optimizer.minimize(phase2_loss, var_list=train_vars) # freeze hidden1

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    training_ops = [phase1_training_op, phase2_training_op]
    reconstruction_losses = [phase1_reconstruction_loss, phase2_reconstruction_loss]
    n_epochs = [4, 4]
    batch_sizes = [150, 150]

    use_cached_results = True

    # Train both phases
    if not use_cached_results:
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init.run()
            for phase in range(2):
                print("Training phase #{}".format(phase + 1))
                for epoch in range(n_epochs[phase]):
                    n_batches = mnist.train.num_examples // batch_sizes[phase]
                    for iteration in range(n_batches):
                        print("\r{}%".format(100 * iteration // n_batches), end="")
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                        X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_sizes[phase])
                        sess.run(training_ops[phase], feed_dict={X: X_batch})
                    loss_train = reconstruction_losses[phase].eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch})
                    print("\r{}".format(epoch), "Train MSE:", loss_train)
                    saver.save(sess, "./my_model_one_at_a_time.ckpt")
            loss_test = reconstruction_loss.eval(feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images})
            print("Test MSE (uncached method):", loss_test)

    # Train both phases, but in this case we cache the frozen layer outputs
    if use_cached_results:
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init.run()
            for phase in range(2):
                print("Training phase #{}".format(phase + 1))
                if phase == 1:
                    hidden1_cache = hidden1.eval(feed_dict={X: mnist.train.images})
                for epoch in range(n_epochs[phase]):
                    n_batches = mnist.train.num_examples // batch_sizes[phase]
                    for iteration in range(n_batches):
                        print("\r{}%".format(100 * iteration // n_batches), end="")
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                        if phase == 1:
                # Phase 2 - use the cached output from hidden layer 1
                            indices = np.random.permutation(mnist.train.num_examples)
                            hidden1_batch = hidden1_cache[indices[:batch_sizes[phase]]]
                            feed_dict = {hidden1: hidden1_batch}
                            sess.run(training_ops[phase], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                        else:
                # Phase 1
                            X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_sizes[phase])
                            feed_dict = {X: X_batch}
                            sess.run(training_ops[phase], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                    loss_train = reconstruction_losses[phase].eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
                    print("\r{}".format(epoch), "Train MSE:", loss_train)
                    saver.save(sess, "./my_model_cache_frozen.ckpt")
            loss_test = reconstruction_loss.eval(feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images})
            print("Test MSE (cached method):", loss_test)


def unsupervised_pretraining():
    reset_graph()

    # Load the dataset to use
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/")

    n_inputs = 28 * 28
    n_hidden1 = 300
    n_hidden2 = 150
    n_outputs = 10

    learning_rate = 0.01
    l2_reg = 0.0005

    activation = tf.nn.elu
    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(l2_reg)
    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])

    weights1_init = initializer([n_inputs, n_hidden1])
    weights2_init = initializer([n_hidden1, n_hidden2])
    weights3_init = initializer([n_hidden2, n_outputs])

    weights1 = tf.Variable(weights1_init, dtype=tf.float32, name="weights1")
    weights2 = tf.Variable(weights2_init, dtype=tf.float32, name="weights2")
    weights3 = tf.Variable(weights3_init, dtype=tf.float32, name="weights3")

    biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_hidden1), name="biases1")
    biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_hidden2), name="biases2")
    biases3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_outputs), name="biases3")

    hidden1 = activation(tf.matmul(X, weights1) + biases1)
    hidden2 = activation(tf.matmul(hidden1, weights2) + biases2)
    logits = tf.matmul(hidden2, weights3) + biases3

    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    reg_loss = regularizer(weights1) + regularizer(weights2) + regularizer(weights3)
    loss = cross_entropy + reg_loss
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    pretrain_saver = tf.train.Saver([weights1, weights2, biases1, biases2])
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    n_epochs = 4
    batch_size = 50
    n_labeled_instances = 2000

    pretraining = True

    # Regular training (without pretraining):
    if not pretraining:
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init.run()
            for epoch in range(n_epochs):
                n_batches = n_labeled_instances // batch_size
                for iteration in range(n_batches):
                    #print("\r{}%".format(100 * iteration // n_batches), end="")
                    #sys.stdout.flush()
                    indices = np.random.permutation(n_labeled_instances)[:batch_size]
                    X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.images[indices], mnist.train.labels[indices]
                    sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
                    accuracy_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
                    print("\r{}".format(epoch), "Train accuracy after each mini-batch:", accuracy_val)
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                accuracy_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
                print("\r{}".format(epoch), "Train accuracy after all batched:", accuracy_val, end=" ")
                saver.save(sess, "./my_model_supervised.ckpt")
                accuracy_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})
                print("Test accuracy (without pretraining):", accuracy_val)

    # Now reuse the first two layers of the autoencoder we pretrained:
    if pretraining:
        training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[weights3, biases3])  # Freeze layers 1 and 2 (optional)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init.run()
            pretrain_saver.restore(sess, "./my_model_cache_frozen.ckpt")
            for epoch in range(n_epochs):
                n_batches = n_labeled_instances // batch_size
                for iteration in range(n_batches):
                    #print("\r{}%".format(100 * iteration // n_batches), end="")
            #sys.stdout.flush()
                    indices = np.random.permutation(n_labeled_instances)[:batch_size]
                    X_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.images[indices], mnist.train.labels[indices]
                    sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
                    accuracy_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
                    print("\r{}".format(epoch), "Train accuracy after each mini-batch:", accuracy_val)
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                accuracy_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
                print("\r{}".format(epoch), "Train accuracy after all batched:", accuracy_val, end=" ")
                saver.save(sess, "./my_model_supervised_pretrained.ckpt")
                accuracy_val = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})
                print("Test accuracy (with pretraining):", accuracy_val)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Seed the random number generator
    np.random.seed(42)
    tf.set_random_seed(42)

    # Fit a multi-layer autoencoder and save the weights
    # - this part is from Aurelien Geron's Ch 15, "Training one Autoencoder at a time in a single graph" example
    train_stacked_autoencoder()

    # Fit a network, using the weights previously saved for pretraining
    # - this part is from Aurelien Geron's Ch 15, "Unsupervised pretraining" example
    unsupervised_pretraining()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to also see the validation/test accuracy of your code, in order to compare it to that in the notebook. The training accuracy on its own can sometimes be a little misleading or _nonrepresentative_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[NOTE: I have not myself worked through Aurélien Geron's tutorials, but I have read the book]*

---

On an intuitive level, I can persuade myself that the training would actually be slower for a pretrained model. In other words, it could make sense that the **rate** at which a error decreases (or accuracy increases) might be lower. The fact that training accuracy is lower is (for me at least) a little more complex and, perhaps, case specific.

#### Rate of learning

> However the pretraining seems to make training slower.

Using a pretrained model, we have essentially taken a set of weights, which are already (at least partially) optimised for one problem. They are geared towards solving that problem based on the dataset they received, which means they expect the input to correspond to a certain distribution. You have frozen the first two layers with this line:

`if pretraining:
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[weights3, biases3])`

Freezing two layers (in your case, out of three), intuitively kind of restricts the model.

Here is a somewhat contrived analogy that I might use to explain such cases to myself. Imagine we had a clown who could juggle with three balls, but now we want them to learn to use a fourth ball. At the same time, we ask an amateur to learn how to juggle, also with four balls. Before measuring their rate of learning, we decide to tie one of the clown's hands behind their back. So the clown already knows some tricks, but is also constrained in some way during the learning process. In my mind, the amateur would most likely learn a lot faster (relatively), as there is more to learn -  but also because they have more freedom to explore the parameter space i.e. they can move more freely using both arms.

In the setting of optimisation, one might imagine that position of the pretrained model on a loss curve is already in a place where gradients are very small in certain dimensions (don't forget, we have a high-dimensional search space). This ends up meaning that it cannot as quickly make changes to the output of the weights whilst backpropagating errors, as the weight updates are multiples of these potentially small optimised weights.

...*Ok - might sounds plausible, but this only addresses the problem of slow learning - what about the fact that the actual training accuracy is lower that that of the model with random initialisation??*

#### Intial training accuracy

> I expected the pretrained network would start with a lower error (compared to the network not using pretraining)...

Here I tend to agree with you. In the optimal case, we could take a pretrained model, use the initial layers as they are and just fine-tune the final layers. There are, however, some cases in which this might not work.

Looking into related literature, there is a possible explanation from the abstract of the paper: [How transferable are features in deep neural networks? (Yosinski et al.)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1792):

> Transferability is negatively affected by two distinct issues: (1) the specialization of higher layer neurons to their original task at the expense of performance on the target task, which was expected, and (2) optimization difficulties related to splitting networks between co-adapted neurons, which was not expected.

I find the second reason to be particularly interesting and relevant to your setup. This is because you actually only have three layers. You are therefore not allowing must freedom to fine-tune, and the final layer was likely very dependent on its relationship to the preceding layer.

What you might expect to see as a result of using a pretrained model, is rather that the final model exhibits better generalisation. This may indeed come at the cost of a lower test accuracy on the hold-out set of the specific dataset you train on.

Here are [another thoughts](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/#tf), summarised well by the amazing (and free) [Stanford CS231n](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/) course:

> *Learning rates*. It’s common to use a smaller learning rate for ConvNet weights that are being fine-tuned, in comparison to the (randomly-initialized) weights for the new linear classifier that computes the class scores of your new dataset.

In your code, the learning rate seems to be fixed for all learning phases at `0.01`. This is something you could experiment with; making it smaller for the pretrained layers, or just starting with a lower learning rate globally.

Here is a [comprehensive introduction to tranfer learning](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/transfer-learning-the-art-of-fine-tuning-a-pre-trained-model/) that might give you some more ideas about why/where you might make some different modelling decisions.